# Python code with function not returning result

Tags: python

```
def area_of_triangle(x,y,z):

   area = abs(float(x[0])*float(y[1]) + float(y[0])*float(z[1]) + float(z[0])*float(x[1]) 
    - float(x[0])*float(z[1]) - float(y[0])*float(x[1]) - float(z[0])*float(y[1]))/ 2

   if area <0:

       return area

   else:

      return "Error. Given co-ordinates don't form a triangle"


def perimeter_of_triangle(x,y,z):

  a = ((float(x[0])-float(y[0]))**2 + (float(y[1])-float(x[1]))**2)**0.5

  b = ((float(y[0])-float(z[0]))**2 + (float(y[1])-float(z[1]))**2)**0.5

  c = ((float(x[0])-float(z[0]))**2 + (float(x[1])-float(z[1]))**2)**0.5
  perimeter = a + b + c

  if (a + b > c) and (a + c > b) and (b + c > a):

    return perimeter

  else:

    return "Error. Given co-ordinates don't form a triangle"

def main():

  f = open("input_pe02.txt","r")

  boolean_value = f.readline()

  x = (f.readline()).split(',')

  y = (f.readline()).split(',')

  z = (f.readline()).split(',')

  if boolean_value.lower() == "false\n":

    print("Area of triangle: ",area_of_triangle(x,y,z))

  else:

    print("Perimeter of triangle: ",perimeter_of_triangle(x,y,z))
```

When I execute this code, no result gets printed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: try removing  \n from "false\n"? 
If not, trace by adding a print statement inside each if condition to test if you are coming inside if condition or not.

Comment: You don't call any function anywhere. That's why you don't see anything printed.

Comment: Because you have only defined the functions. You've called none of them

Comment: If you come from C, note that `main` is nothing special in Python. You have to call it explicitely if you want to run it.

Comment: Just initiate execution using main() at the end

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the file add following code to call the main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def area_of_triangle(x,y,z):

  area = abs(float(x[0])*float(y[1]) + float(y[0])*float(z[1]) + float(z[0])*float(x[1]) 
        - float(x[0])*float(z[1]) - float(y[0])*float(x[1]) - float(z[0])*float(y[1]))/ 2

  if area <0:

    return area

  else:

    return "Error. Given co-ordinates don't form a triangle"


def perimeter_of_triangle(x,y,z):

  a = ((float(x[0])-float(y[0]))**2 + (float(y[1])-float(x[1]))**2)**0.5

  b = ((float(y[0])-float(z[0]))**2 + (float(y[1])-float(z[1]))**2)**0.5

  c = ((float(x[0])-float(z[0]))**2 + (float(x[1])-float(z[1]))**2)**0.5
  perimeter = a + b + c

  if (a + b > c) and (a + c > b) and (b + c > a):

    return perimeter

  else:

    return "Error. Given co-ordinates don't form a triangle"

def main():

  f = open("input_pe02.txt","r")

  boolean_value = f.readline()

  x = (f.readline()).split(',')

  y = (f.readline()).split(',')

  z = (f.readline()).split(',')

  if boolean_value.lower() == "false\n":

    print("Area of triangle: ",area_of_triangle(x,y,z))

  else:

    print("Perimeter of triangle: ",perimeter_of_triangle(x,y,z))


main()
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

All those conversions to `float` can be avoided by merely mapping x, y, z to `float()`:

```
  x = list(map(float, f.readline().split(','))

  y = list(map(float, f.readline().split(','))

  z = list(map(float, f.readline().split(','))
```

When something goes wrong in the code, you do not return a string, but throw an exception:

```
if area <0:

    return area

  else:

    raise ValueError( "Error. Given co-ordinates don't form a triangle")
```

Also, use

```
  if bool(boolean_value):
```

instead of:

```
  if boolean_value.lower() == "false\n
```

And last, but not the least, you have to call your function for it to execute:

```
main()
```